# Need to install Perl AND Linux

Tags: git, perl, docker, yum

I know how to use a Dockerfile to get the Perl I need:

```
FROM perl:latest
RUN curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
RUN cpanm JSON
RUN cpanm Data::Dump
RUN cpanm -f XML::SAX
RUN cpanm XML::SAX::Expat
RUN cpanm XML::Simple
```

But I also want to install git and make because I want to clone my perl code and then cd into a directory and run it using `make`.

But adding

```
RUN yum install git
```

to the above, produced the error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: yum: not found
```

Can someone suggest an approach to this? I've tried by starting with Linux and doing a

```
RUN yum install perl
```

but then I don't get a Perl that works as smoothly as the offical one. In particular, it chokes when I try to add the modules I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By having a look at the `Dockerfile` of the [official perl image](https://github.com/perl/docker-perl/blob/r20150602.0/5.020.002-64bit,threaded/Dockerfile) I saw that `apt-get` is available. So you could just do this instead of using `yum`:

```
apt-get install -y git
```